# Inconsistent results from taking average of two RGB values

Tags: java, image-processing, rgb, rgba

Why are those pixel rgb values sometimes equal and sometimes not equal? I am learning image processing. It would be great if someone help me out here.

```
public class ColorTest1 {

    Color p1;
    Color p2;

    ColorTest1() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("d:\\x.jpg"));
        for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth() - 1; x++) {
                p1 = new Color(bi.getRGB(x, y));
                p2 = new Color(bi.getRGB(x + 1, y));

                int a = (p1.getAlpha() + p2.getAlpha()) / 2;
                int r = (p1.getRed() + p2.getRed()) / 2;
                int g = (p1.getGreen() + p2.getGreen()) / 2;
                int b = (p1.getBlue() + p2.getBlue()) / 2;

                int x1 = p1.getRGB();
                int x2 = p2.getRGB();

                int sum1 = (x1 + x2) / 2;

                int sum2 = a * 16777216 + r * 65536 + g * 256 + b;
                System.out.println(sum1 == sum2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... areg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new ColorTest1();
    }
}
```

This is the image:

[image: This is the image]

Comment: There should be no expectation that `(x1 + x2) / 2` would work in general. It completely ignores the channels. You can average two colours (ignoring the semantics of the alpha channel) with `(a & b) + (((a ^ b) & 0xFEFEFEFE) >>> 1)`

Comment: did not get it. can you please tell me easy way so i can understand. no jokes though.

Comment: why sum1=(x1 + x2) / 2 and sum2 are not equal. but sometime sum1 and sum2 are equal

Comment: There is nothing really interesting going on, when they're equal it's essentially luck. For comparison, you might ask why sometimes you can add two numbers by simply adding the digits, but not always. The only difference there is carries, here there are both inter-channel carries (which shouldn't happen) and the `/2` also causes some trouble.

Comment: You keep asking this sort of question about colours, and yes in general *you have to care* that something is specifically a colour and not "just any `int`", they *do not* work the same way.

Comment: @harold i have posted another question. can look into it please.

Comment: I can answer it tomorrow if you don't have an answer by then

Comment: great. ill be waiting. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two pixels. One is black. The other is nearly black but with a slight bit of red in it, just 1/255. Ignore alpha. `r` will be (0 + 1) / 2 = 0. `g` and `b` will be 0 too. `x1` will be 0. `x2` will be 65536, right? So `sum1` will be 65536 / 2 = 32768. `sum2` obviously will be 0.

Whenever the sum of either red or green of the two colours is odd, the `int` division will set the high bit of the next colour in RGB, leading to an unexpected result.

Comment: thnaks. i got it.

Comment: That’s on the border. I had to improve the question a little bit before I could defend doing that. :-) @NEKIBURRAHMAN